# shape not being drawn to the canvas javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I am making a game engine called Forge.js. I have a Polygon method in a Entity class and it is not drawing the shapes. It loops through points and draws a line to each of the points. The lines however aren't being drawn. help plz

polygon method:

```
_polygon(points){
        const local_ctx = new Path2D()

        this.ctx.beginPath()

        var j = 3

        local_ctx.moveTo(points[0], points[1])
        
        for (var i=0; i<=points.length; i++){
            local_ctx.lineTo(points[i+2], points[i+j])

            j += 2

        }

        this.ctx.fillStyle = constants.COLORS.black
        this.ctx.fill()

    }
```

Comment: Did you try `this.ctx.fill(local_ctx)`? Take a look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Path2D/Path2D.

Comment: Why do you even create this `Path2D` if you don't use it?

Comment: i gave up on Forge.js. I just realized I can't multitask shapes with canvas, efficiently fill the shapes, and have 2 functions that load different shapes at the same time

Answer (score 0):

As has been said in the comments, you need to pass the Path2D object to `fill()` in order for the context to draw it.
But this isn't the only issue with your code.

Your for loop probably doesn't do what you expected:

```js
// Rewrote in order to log the indexes that are beign used in the loop
var j = 3

console.log(0, 1)

for (var i=0; i<=10; i++){
    console.log(i+2, i+j)
    j += 2
}
```

You can actually simplify this loop a lot by taking advantage of the fact that an empty subpath doesn't require an initial `moveTo` call. `lineTo(x, y)` gets automatically converted to `moveTo(x, y)` if your path is empty.
So we can treat all our points the same, all in a single for loop that only increments our index by 2.

```js
const constants = { COLORS: { BLACK: "#000" } };
const obj = {
  ctx: document.createElement("canvas").getContext("2d"),
  _polygon(points){
        const local_ctx = new Path2D()

// Since we're using a Path2D object we don't need to do anything
// on the context's subpath
//        this.ctx.beginPath() 


        for (var i=0; i<=points.length; i+=2){
            local_ctx.lineTo(points[i], points[i+1])
        }

        this.ctx.fillStyle = constants.COLORS.black
        this.ctx.fill(local_ctx) // fill the context using the Path2D object

    }
};
document.body.append(obj.ctx.canvas);
obj._polygon([13, 13, 13, 50, 50, 50]);
```